# Remove filter in Excel form an imported Access data file in VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, import, vba

I import from Access to Excel a data (tables) file, but I don't manage to remove the filter. I get a 1004 error (Delete of Range is failed). I also can't remove it by hand.

```
Sub Openaccessdatafile()

'Niet blad updaten
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets.Add.Name = "Gegevens alginaten"
  Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Gegevens alginaten")
LR = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Filename = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel files (*.xls*), *.xls*")
 MsgBox Filename
If Filename <> False Then
  Workbooks.Open (Filename)
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy sh.Range("A" & LR)
  ActiveWorkbook.Close
 Sheets("Start").Cells(2, 5).Value = "Ok"
Else
 MsgBox "Geen bestand aangeklikt."
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 Sheets("Gegevens alginaten").Delete
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If

'Wel blad updaten
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Sheets("Start").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Good remark. As you can see I import the file from an Excel file, which is exported from Access to Excel.

Comment: I assume you're trying to remove a filter from the workbook you open (there's nothing in the code) - is it formatted as a Table or a regular range?

Comment: It is formatted as a table with a filter on the first row, with a certain layout. The cell property is (mentioned) locked, but even with removing this I don't manage to remove the line, while I can remove the second line with values. Just like this: [link](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/072909_0430_FilteronSel5.png)

Comment: What are you actually trying to do - remove the filter dropdowns altogether, or just clear any applied filter?

Comment: Remove the filter dropdowns altogether (remove row 1). I can't find it in Access directly to remove it. So maybe do it through VBA at Access and export it?

Comment: You should be able to just turn off the Header row in the Table design.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently exporting it with Access through a VBA macro button does work better. Than I could remove the row, because the filter is than not added in the exported file.